# c# list and csv file reading

Tags: c#

hello guys this is my code in C#  .netcore 6

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\ho3in\source\repos\dataset\data\orders.csv"))
{
    using (var Csvreader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var records = Csvreader.GetRecords<datamodel>().ToList();
        
        
         
        
    }
    
}
public class datamodel
    {
        public int ID_Order { get; set; }
        public int ID_Customer { get; set; }
        public int ID_Item { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime_CartFinalize { get; set; }
        public float Amount_Gross_Order { get; set; }
        public string city_name_fa { get; set; }
        public float Quantity_item { get; set; }
    }
```

i want to print my data but im just gettin `dataset.datamodel' printed out how can i access the data and work with it btw im using the csvhelper lib

[image: this is how my data looks like in locals]

i want to access my data and work with it such  as print the data search by user etc..

Comment: _gettin `dataset.datamodel' printed_ There isn't any code that prints anything here. Please add the code that does the printing.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with csv or csvhelper. It does not change if you would hard code the elements or get them via web request.

Comment: Use `record` instead `class` for `datamodel` then you will have readable data anywhere. 
...
var records =  Csvreader.GetRecords<datamodel>().ToList();
records.Foreach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a list of objects of your type.

`var records = Csvreader.GetRecords<datamodel>().ToList();`

If you want to print it, then use properties of your class:

```
foreach(var record in records)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{record.ID_Customer}, {record.ID_Item}, {record.DateTime_CartFinalize}");
}
```

You can also override ToString method as stuartd mentioned:

```
public class datamodel
{
    // properties and others

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{ID_Customer}, {ID_Item}, {DateTime_CartFinalize}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Or override `ToString()`

Comment: Or just serialise it using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`